# FastAPI - GET Request with Pydantic List field

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm new to FastAPI (migrating from Flask) and I'm trying to create a Pydantic model for my `GET` route:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter,Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional,List

router = APIRouter()

class SortModel(BaseModel):
    field:    Optional[str]
    directions: List[str]

@router.get("/pydanticmodel")
def get_sort(criteria: SortModel = Depends(SortModel)):
    pass #my code for handling this route.....
```

When I'm running  `curl -X GET http://localhost:XXXX/pydanticmodel?directions=up&directions=asc&field=id`  I'm getting `422 Unprocessable Entity: {"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

But if I'm changing `directions:List[str]` -> `directions: str` I'm getting `200 OK` with `directions="asc"`.
What is the reason that `str` works for query param and `List[str]` does not? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is not, as yet, possible to use a `GET` request with Pydantic `List` field as `query` parameter. When you declare a `List` field in the Pydantic model, it is interpreted as a request `body` parameter, instead of a `query` one (regardless of using `Depends()`—you can check that through Swagger UI docs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, for instance). Additionally, as you are using a `GET` request, even if you added the `List` of `directions` in the `body` and attempted sending the request, it wouldn't work, as a `POST` request would be required for that operation.

The way to do this is to either define the `List` of `directions` explicitly with `Query` as a separate parameter in your endpoint, or implement your query parameter-parsing in a separate dependency class, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1). Remember again to [define the `List` field explicitly with `Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values), so that `directions` can be interpreted as a query parameter and appear multiple times in the URL (in others words, to receive multiple values). Example:

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Query

class SortModel:
    def __init__(
        self,
        field:  Optional[str],
        directions: List[str] = Query(...)
    ):
        self.field = field
        self.directions = directions

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/")
def send_user(criteria: SortModel = Depends()):
    return criteria
```

The above can be re-written using the [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) decorator, as shown below:

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Query
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class SortModel:
    field:    Optional[str]
    directions: List[str] = Query(...)

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/")
def send_user(criteria: SortModel = Depends()):
    return criteria
```

### Update

You could now wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()`, which would allow you to define a Pydantic `List` field that will be interpreted as query parameter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. The following solution will work, but it isn't really what I want however maybe it's good enough for you:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter,Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional,List

router = APIRouter()

class SortModel(BaseModel):
    field:    Optional[str]

@router.get("/pydanticmodel")
def get_sort(criteria: SortModel = Depends(SortModel), directions: List[str] = Query(...)):
    pass #my code for handling this route.....
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not a Pydantic or FastAPI problem.

If you want to send an array with curl you should use **-d** flag.

```
In: curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pydanticmodel?field=123"  -d "[\"string\"]"
Out: {"field":"123","directions":["string"]}
```

Now your code should work perfectly.