# FastAPI POST request with List input raises 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: python, list, python-requests, fastapi, http-status-code-422

I would like to write a `POST` request in which an input parameter is a `list`, but I got error `422 unprocessable entity`:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

My `POST` request is:

```
@router.post('',status_code=200)
def register(reg_id: int, reg_name: str, reg_option_list:List[int]):
    reg_item = My_DB(
        id=reg_id,
        name=reg_name,
        option_list=reg_option_list,
    )
    item = db.query(My_DB).filter(My_DB.id == service_id).first()

    if item is not None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Item exists.")
    db.add(reg_item)
    db.commit()
    return reg_item
```

But when I change my code like below, remove list input and set the value in code as a list, everything works fine:

```
@router.post('',status_code=200)
def register(reg_id: int, reg_name: str,):
    reg_item = My_DB(
        id=reg_id,
        name=reg_name,
        option_list=[1,2,3],
    )
    item = db.query(My_DB).filter(My_DB.id == service_id).first()

    if item is not None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Item exists.")
    db.add(reg_item)
    db.commit()
    return reg_item
```

I will appreciate any help about my `list` input parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values) (have a look under the "Tip" section)

> To declare a query parameter with a type of `list`, like in the example
> above, you **need to explicitly use** `Query`, otherwise it would be
> interpreted as a `request body`.

Thus, by declaring a `List` parameter in the way you do, the endpoint will expect to receive it in the request `body`, rather than in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) as a `query` parameter. Hence, a `422 unprocessable entity` error is raised, including the specific details you provided (i.e., `body` field is missing). You could also confirm that through OpenAPI/Swagger UI at `/docs`, for instance, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs`. You would see that the value for `reg_option_list` is expected to be passed to the `Request body` section, not in the query parameters.

### Option 1 - Send `List` of data in the query string

The way to do this is to [define the query parameter explicitly with `Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values); thus, allowing the parameter to appear multiple times in the URL. Since such a request would not include a request body, you should rather use a `GET` request, which is used when one requests data from the server, whereas `POST` is used to send data to the server stored in the request body.

#### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from typing import List


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def register(reg_id: int, reg_name: str, reg_options: List[int] = Query(...)):
    return reg_options
```

**Test URL with `Query` parameters `List`**:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?reg_id=1&reg_name=foo&reg_options=1&reg_options=2&reg_options=3
```

**Test using Python requests:**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?reg_id=1&reg_name=foo&reg_options=1&reg_options=2&reg_options=3'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

or, preferably:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
params = {'reg_id': 1, 'reg_name': 'foo', 'reg_options': [1, 2, 3]}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(r.text)
```

### Option 2 - Send `List` of data in the request body

If you would like to use a `POST` request and send the data in the request body instead, you could simply define the `reg_options` parameter above in the same way, **but** without using the `= Query(...)` part. This should tell FastAPI to expect a list of data for that endpoint in the body of the request. For more details and examples on how to send data in the request body to a FastAPI backend, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804). Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554017/17865804).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried this as documentation but got error 500 and "invalid input syntax for type integer"

Comment: I used  ```option_list = {"option": reg_option_list}``` and it is about the option value
with this details ```invalid input syntax for type integer: "option"```

Comment: I edited it to : option_list =[reg_option_list] and it works perfectly.