# How to set Swagger UI to use List fields in query parameters using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi, pydantic

When making an app that uses dependency injection with a list field, the parameter automatically goes to the request body in SwaggerUI:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List


class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)
    ages: List[int] = Field([])


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
def test(query: QueryParams = Depends()):
    return "hi"

uvicorn.run(app)
```

[image: SwaggerUI]

Which means I cant test it in swagger UI. Even if I change field to query, it still doesn't work:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List


class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)
    ages: List[int] = Query([])  # <-- Query


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
def test(query: QueryParams = Depends()):
    return "hi"

uvicorn.run(app)
```

If I put it in the route function, it works:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List


class QueryParams(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(...)


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
def test(query: QueryParams = Depends(), ages: List[int] = Query([])):
    return "hi"

uvicorn.run(app)
```

[image: Working UI]

How can I get swagger UI to recognize a list query field in a basemodel with dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804), one can't use a `List` field inside a Pydantic model and expect it to be a `query` parameter. The way to do this is to implement your query parameter-parsing in a separate [dependency class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1), as shown below:

```py
class QueryParams:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        ages: List[int] = Query(...)
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.ages = ages
        
@app.get("/test")
def test(query: QueryParams = Depends()):
    return "hi"
```

The above can be re-written using the [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) decorator, as shown below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class QueryParams:
    name: str
    ages: List[int] = Query(...)

@app.get("/test")
def test(query: QueryParams = Depends()):
    return "hi"
```

### Update

One could wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` that would allow them to define a `List` field as query parameter inside the Pydantic model. A working example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804).

Comment: Do you know why we cant use a query parameter in a base model for a list field? Is it a design decision?

Comment: Could be. There is an extensive discussion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/318), if you would like to have a look.