# is there a way to return a list of map from a HTML form on fastapi

Tags: python, forms, jinja2, fastapi, pydantic

i am trying to get map value from html form on fastapi in this format

> [EmploymentHistory(work_description='3wert', location='ADSF'), EmploymentHistory(work_description='3wert', location='cghvjbn,m')]
> or
> [{'work_description': '3wert', 'location': '2q3wer'}, {'work_description': '3wert', 'location': 'ADSF'}]

while using fastapi this is my endpoint below

```
@app.post('/formz', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def post_formz(request: Request,data: EmploymentHistory = Depends(EmploymentHistory.as_form)):
print(data)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("resume/create.html",{"request": request})
```

my pydantic schema below

```
class EmploymentHistory(BaseModel):
    work_description: str 
    location: str 

    @classmethod
    def as_form(
        cls,
        work_description: str = Form(...),
        location: str = Form(...)
    ):
        return cls(
            work_description=work_description,
            location= location,
        )
```

this is my html below if needed:

```html
<form method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p>Employment History</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ol id="employment_history-form">
            <li>
                <label for= 'work_description'>Work discription</label>
                <input type='work_description' required="required" name='work_description' placeholder='jone briggs' />
                <label for= 'location'>Location</label>
                <input type='location' required="required" name='location' placeholder='jone briggs' />
            </li> 
            <li>
                <label for= 'work_description'>Work discription</label>
                <input type='work_description' required="required" name='work_description' placeholder='jone briggs' />
                <label for= 'location'>Location</label>
                <input type='location' required="required" name='location' placeholder='jone briggs' />
            </li>     
        </ol>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" >create history</button>
</form>
```

tried wrapping the class in a list

```
@app.post('/formz', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def post_formz(request: Request,data: List[EmploymentHistory] = Depends(List[EmploymentHistory.as_form])):
```

but i got the error below

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","args"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["query","kwargs"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

i don't know why but i also tried nesting the class into another class like below

```
class User(BaseModel):
    employments_history: List[EmploymentHistory]

    @classmethod
    def as_form(
        cls,
        employments_history: List[EmploymentHistory] = List[EmploymentHistory.as_form],
    ):
        return cls(
            employments_history=employments_history,
        )
```

which resulting in me getting the error below

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid list","type":"type_error.list"}]}
```

so i removed the list from the schema which is now

```
class User(BaseModel):
    employments_history: EmploymentHistory

    @classmethod
    def as_form(
        cls,
        employments_history: EmploymentHistory = EmploymentHistory.as_form,
    ):
        return cls(
            employments_history=employments_history,
        )
```

which now gives me the error below

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

i found a way around it which was with the zip function and making the string a list in the schema like below

```
class EmploymentList(BaseModel):
    work_description: List[str] 
    location: List[str] 

    @classmethod
    def as_form(
        cls,
        work_description: List[str] = Form(...),
        location: List[str] = Form(...)
    ):
        return cls(
            work_description=work_description,
            location= location
        )
```

and the end point below

```
@app.post('/formz', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def post_formz(request: Request,data: EmploymentHistory = Depends(EmploymentHistory.as_form)):
    employment= []
    for a, b in zip(data.work_description, data.location):
        l = EmploymentHistory(work_description=a,location=b)
        employment.append(l.dict())

    print(employment)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("resume/create.html",{"request": request})
```

which gives me what i want but i don't want to have to create a loop. so is there a way to accomplish this without the loop

Comment: See related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).

Comment: @Chris it didn't i got an assertion error. AssertionError: Param: data can only be a request body, using Body()