# How to allow hyphen (-) in query parameter name using FastAPI?

Tags: python, query-string, fastapi, pydantic

I have a simple application below:

```py
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Input(BaseModel):
    a: Annotated[str, Query(..., alias="your_name")]


@app.get("/")
def test(inp: Annotated[Input, Depends()]):
    return f"Hello {inp.a}"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`curl "http://127.0.0.1:8001/?your_name=amin"` returns "Hello amin"

---

I now **change the alias from `your_name` to `your-name`**.

```py
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Input(BaseModel):
    a: Annotated[str, Query(..., alias="your-name")]


@app.get("/")
def test(inp: Annotated[Input, Depends()]):
    return f"Hello {inp.a}"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8001/?your-name=amin"` returns:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","extra_data"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

---

However, hyphened alias in a simpler application is allowed.

```py
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def test(a: Annotated[str, Query(..., alias="your-name")]):
    return f"Hello {a}"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`curl "http://127.0.0.1:8001/?your-name=amin"` returns "Hello Amin"

---

---

Is this a bug? what is the problem here?

Comment: Does `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8001/?your%2Dname=amin"` work?

Comment: no. the same error response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem Overview

As explained [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5250#issuecomment-1209705337) by @JarroVGIT, this is a behaviour coming from Pydantic, not FastAPI. If you looked closely at the error you posted:

```json
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","extra_data"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

it talks about a missing value for a query parameter named `extra_data`—however, there is no such a parameter defined in your `BaseModel`. If, in fact, you used the Swagger UI autodocs at `/docs`, you would see that your endpoint is expecting a required parameter named `extra_data`. As noted by @JarroVGIT in the linked discussion above:

> Whenever you give a 'non-pythonic' alias (like with dashes/hyphens), the
> signature that `inspect.signature()` will get from that `BaseModel`
> subclass will be grouped in the kwargs `extra_data`.

Hence the error about the missing value for `extra_data` query parameter.

### Solution 1

You could wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804). Example:

```py
from fastapi import Query, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Input(BaseModel):
    a: str = Field(Query(..., alias="your-name"))


@app.get("/")
def main(i: Input = Depends()):
    pass
```

### Solution 2

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), you could use a separate [dependency class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1), instead of a `BaseModel`. Example:

```py
from fastapi import Query, Depends
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Input:
    a: str = Query(..., alias="your-name")


@app.get("/")
def main(i: Input = Depends()):
    pass
```

### Solution 3

Declare the query parameter directly in the endpoint, instead of using a Pydantic `BaseModel`. Example:

```py
from fastapi import Query

@app.get("/")
def main(a: str = Query(..., alias="your-name")):
    pass
```

Comment: In your first solution, could you write it with `Annotated`?

Comment: the question is can I have Annotated and Field and Query in the same line?

Comment: `a: Annotated[str, Field(Query(..., alias=` in fastapi version 0.95.1

Comment: The question is about how to use hyphens in query parameters, when these are defined within a Pydantic model. [_"Python itself doesn't do anything with this `Annotated`"_](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#type-hints-with-metadata-annotations), and there is nothing preventing one from using `=` instead (regardless of the FastAPI version one might be using) - it serves the same purpose. In fact, there are cases, just like in Solution 1, where one needs to use `=` instead, as there stiil seem to be issues with `Annotated`.

Comment: Also, please [_"have in mind that when using `Query` inside of `Annotated` you cannot use the default parameter for `Query`"_](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-as-the-default-value-or-in-annotated), as shown in your question.

Comment: I submitted an issue in the fastapi github issues https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9472