# How to set custom JSON parameter name with pydantic?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have JSON with params from DB:

```
{
"model": "Example",
"weight": "1"
}
```

I need to change "model" key in output JSON with pydantic (set it custom name)

```
{
"changed_key": "Example",
"weight": "1"
}
```

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333692) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76137214/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `serialization_alias`
parameter

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Model(BaseModel):
    model: str = Field(..., serialization_alias='changed_key')
    weight: str
```

Docs: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/fields/#field-aliases