# How can I pass a parameter list to FastAPI using request?

Tags: python, request, fastapi

I send the list as param:

```py
import requests
def test():
    params = {"test_param": [1, 2, 3]}
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/test", params=params, timeout=20)
    response_data = response.json()
    print(response_data)
```

and handle everything with FastAPI

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test")
def test(test_param: list):
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": test})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("minimal:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000,
                workers=2)  # Use the on_starting event)
```

and I get the error `"GET /test?test_param=1&test_param=2&test_param=3 HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity`, but I thought that listing the parameter multiple times is the desired way of how FastAPI wants to receive lists...

My error might be that I am not using typing as described here, but imho that shouldn't influence the result as typing is ignored by python anyway: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values

Comment: How to identify parameters if they all have the same name ?

Comment: It's a list so I assume that the first element has index 0 and the n-th index n-1. Afaik this is a standard.

Comment: Well that is strange. Even whe I copy/pasta the docs' sample, I don't have the same /docs display. Are you sure you have the fastapi version that matches the doc you are reading ?

Comment: Related answers to the one above can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804)

Comment: As for returning a JSON response from the FastAPI backend, you might want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) as well