# fastapi swagger docs not rendering list array as query parameter

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

According to the docs it is possible to pass a list of values https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values .

I have tried on my end and the endpoint http://localhost:8000/items/?q=foo&q=bar correctly process the values as a list:

```
{"q":["foo","bar"]}
```

But the docs do not, and interpret it as a string and do not render multiple options:

[image]

Here is my `main.py`:

```
from db import engine,get_db
from models import Example,ExampleModel,Base,Color,Item
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,Query,Path
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy import select
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Annotated,Union,List
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan) # type: ignore


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: Annotated[List[str] | None, Query()] = None):
    query_items = {"q": q}
    return query_items
```

Comment: Could you please try it without using `Annotated`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804)?

Comment: @Chris I think using `Annotated` is preferred way now because of pydantic2.0.

Comment: `Annotated[List[str], Query()] = None` does the thing. But it looks incorrect:')

Comment: `async def read_items(q: list[str] | None = Query(default=None)): ` tried but didn't work

Comment: worked for me yes: `Annotated[list[str],Query()] = None):` but pylance complains about typing